# How to read "Contributing Artist" metadata in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, frameworks

Windows 7 has a very nifty way of showing "Contributing Artist" metadata in Windows Explorer.  In wonder how can I access that metadata from C++? Maybe you even point to some source code? Greatly appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can limit your app to Windows Vista and later, use [IPropertyStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761474(VS.85).aspx).  Otherwise each file type needs to be parsed independently.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're talking about MP3s, I'd guess it uses [ID3 tags](http://www.id3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I found this [metadata reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MetaDataReader.aspx) worked well with mp3 and wma files.